# Telerik MVC Grid Edit Template DropDownList problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I am getting a null value passed to my ajax   .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "AptProfile") in my controller when using the dropdownlist client Edit Template.

property in my FormViewModel that my grid is bound to:

```
  [UIHint("BuildingsGrid"), Required]
                [DisplayName("Building ID")]
                 public int BuildingID
                {
                    get;
                    set;
                }).
```

Here is my view:

```
 <%= Html.Telerik().Grid<PayRent.Models.AptProfileFormViewModel1>()
                    .Name("Profiles")
                    .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(c => c.AptProfileID))
                                    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
                    .DataBinding(binding => 
                        {
                            binding.Ajax()
                            .Select("GetProfiles", "AptProfile")
                            .Insert("_InsertAjaxEditing", "AptProfile")
                            .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "AptProfile")
                            .Delete("_DeleteAjaxEditing", "AptProfile");

                        })

                    .Columns(columns => 
                    {
                        columns.Bound(o => o.AptProfileID);
                        columns.Bound(o => o.BuildingID);
                        columns.Bound(o => o.AptID);
                        columns.Bound(o => o.AptRate);
                        columns.Bound(o => o.AptSize);
                        columns.Bound(o => o.MoveInDate);
                        columns.Command(s =>
                        {
                            s.Edit();
                            s.Delete();


                        });


                    })
                                    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                                    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnEdit("onEdit"))
                    .Pageable()
            %>
    </p>

 <script type="text/javascript">

function onEdit(e) {
//            $(e.form).find('#BuildingsGrid').data('tDropDownList').select(function (dataItem) {
//                return dataItem.Text == e.dataItem['BuildingGrid'];
//            });
        }


    </script>



My EditTemplate:

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
        .Name("BuildingsGrid")
            .BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Buildings"], "BuildingID", "Name"))
%>)
```

Here is my Controller:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    //[CultureAwareAction]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _SaveAjaxEditing(int id, int? BuildingGrid)
    {
        ApartmentProfileRepository repo = new ApartmentProfileRepository();
        AptProfile profile = repo.Get(id);

        TryUpdateModel(profile);
        repo.Save();
        return View(new GridModel(GetAllProfiles()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to match up the name of your column in the view with the name of your edit template and controller action parameter. I don't think the int parameter needs to be nullable in the controller action.

Then in your controller action you need to set the ViewData["Buildings"] for the edit template; then select the current value in your profile object before returning the view.

e.g.

```
public ActionResult _SaveAjaxEditing(int id, int BuildingsGrid)
    {
        ApartmentProfileRepository repo = new ApartmentProfileRepository();
        AptProfile profile = repo.Get(id);

        // Save the building ID in the profile
        profile.BuildingID = BuildingsGrid;

        TryUpdateModel(profile);
        repo.Save();

        // Load the Building objects into the ViewData
        ViewData["Buildings"] = GetBuildings();

        return View(new GridModel(GetAllProfiles()));
    }
```

Comment: Winger, is there a way to accomplish this without using ViewData? I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish this by accessing a SelectList property on my Model, but can't work it out.

Comment: campbelt, what about using a helper object to return the enumerable list of Building objects. In the edit template, replace the ViewData with your helper class method. Just remember, this only gets rendered once before the grid data is bound and then the same list is used for each row.

Comment: Thanks, Winger. I'll look into that. In the meantime, do you happen to know of a good example of this sort of thing that I can look at?

Comment: The most complete example I've seen is Telerik's online demo here:  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/clientedittemplates. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have the same issue. I followed 1st and 2nd. But I am not getting the newly selected value in the dropdownlist. The code is almost same here. Only difference is I m using Server(not ajax )binding.  demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/clientedittemplates.  This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198163/how-to-get-the-new-value-from-telerik-mvc-extension-grid-on-template-editing

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep everything Ajax-ified, you have do it without using the viewbag.  My combobox is in a separate editor template.  All you have to do is return the SelectList as a JsonResult.  That said, I only recommended doing it that way if you expect the data in that combobox to change while the user is on the page, because it calls the server method every time the combo is opened.

In my example below, because the user can add a Category on the same page as they're selecting a Category, I need it to hit the server each time.  But on other pages, I use server-side binding (via the ViewBag/ViewData) so that it only hits the server once.

My editor template:

```
@(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
.Name("YourNameGoesHere")
.DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("SelectCategoriesForComboBox","Shared")))
```

Then in the controller:

```
public EquipmentEntities db = new EquipmentEntities();
public List<SelectListItem> CategoryList
{
    get
    {
        var m = db.Categories
        .Select(e => new{ Id = e.Id, Name = e.Name })
        .OrderBy(e => e.name);
        List<SelectListItem> sl = new SelectListItem(m.ToList(), "Id", "Name").ToList();

        //insert a blank item as the first entry
        sl.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = string.Empty }));
        return sl;
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectCategoryForComboBox()
{
    return new JsonResult { Data = CategoryList };
}
```

Maybe I'm a little bit late, but hopefully it helps someone out.